# C++ template stack map/multimap

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management, stack, multimap

I have to measure how much time it takes to add 100000 int type numbers to containers of different types. So there's **standard**, **vector**, **list** - these are done correctly. And I've got problem to do **map** and **multimap**, and then I have to measure how much time it takes to delete all of those elements for each container. Any clues?

> Each container has to hold 100000 int type numbers.
>
> 1. Create a stack container (s1). Measure how much time it takes to add 100000 numbers to it.
> 2. Create a stack container (s2), which will manage memory like vector container. Measure how much time it takes to add 100000 numbers to it.
> 3. Create a stack container (s3), which will manage memory like list container. Measure how much time it takes to add 100000 numbers to it.
> 4. Create a stack container (s2), which will manage memory like map container. Measure how much time it takes to add 100000 numbers to it.
> 5. Create a stack container (s2), which will manage memory like multimap container. Measure how much time it takes to add 100000
>    numbers to it.
> 6. Measure how much time it takes to delete elements for all of the containers.
>
> Additional info:
>
> 1. Use standard C++ time counting method. Time counting can be made this way:
>
> ```
> clock_t begin = clock();
> //instructions
> clock_t end = clock();
> double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
> cout << elapsed_secs <<endl;
> ```
>
> 2. Use two types of own stack implementation:
>
> - not optimized (working correctly and undirected for obtaining less time-consuming operation)
> - optimized (working correctly, but also directed to obtain less time-consuming operation)
>
> also implementation based on standard stack<> class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


template <class T>
void timeTest(T s)
{
    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { s.push(i); }
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << elapsed_secs << endl;
}

/*
template <class T, class S>
void timeTest(stack <int, map <int, int>> s)
{
    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { s.emplace(i, i); }
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << elapsed_secs << endl;
}

template <class T, class S>
void timeTest(stack <pair <int, int>, multimap <int, int>> s)
{
    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { s.emplace(i, i); }
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << elapsed_secs << endl;
}
*/


int main()
{
    stack <int> s1;
    stack <int, vector <int>> s2;
    stack <int, list <int>> s3;
    //stack <int, map <int, int>> s4;
    //stack<pair<int, int>, multimap<int, int>> s5;


    timeTest(s1);
    timeTest(s2);
    timeTest(s3);
    //timeTest(s4);
    //timeTest(s5);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you have??

Comment: same question has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67963760/c-template-class-stack-map-multimap

Comment: The commented section (4.) - I have to put 100000 elements in map and measure time

Comment: `std::map` doesn't satisfy requirement of [`stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)... Why do you use `stack` adapter for your testing?

Comment: I suggest using a benchmarking tool for doing benchmarking. https://quick-bench.com/ is quite nice.

Comment: "I have to write some code as my homework" is not a question. Please try to explain what you tried already, how it failed, and what is missing.

Comment: I'm mainly concerned about first commented template part. I tried it with different arguments and the one that worked was void timeTest(stack <map <int, int>> s) but when I tried putting emplace in 'instructions' it crashed again

Comment: "crashed" how? Did it compile, or did compilation fail? Was there an error? Were there any warnings? What happened when you ran it with your debugger and then let it crash?

Comment: template <>
void timeTest(stack <map <int, int>> s)

stack <map <int, int>> s4;

these are the changes that worked partially

Comment: please show the code that has the problems and describe the problems in detail. The code you did post is the one that compiles and works fine, no? (it does here:https://godbolt.org/z/er4xKjj3M). Please read about [mre]

Comment: Notice also that `std::map<int, int>`/`std::multimap<int, int>` are more "equivalent" to `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` than `std::vector<int>` (`std::set` would be the alternative (but doesn't fit neither `std::stack` requirement)).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void test(T t,const int I = 1000000) {
    clock_t begin = clock();
    cout << "Uzupelnianie:\t";
    for (int i = 0; i <= I; i++) {
        t.push(i);
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << elapsed_secs << endl;
    cout << "Usuwanie:\t";
    begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i <= I; i++) {
        t.pop();
    }
    end = clock();
    elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << elapsed_secs << endl;
}


template<class T>
class Mapa {
public:
    map<T, T> mapa;
    using value_type = typename T;
    using reference = typename map<T, T>::reference;
    using const_reference = typename map<T, T>::const_reference;
    using size_type = typename map<T, T>::size_type;
    using container_type = map<T, T>;
    
    
    void push_back(T i) {
        mapa.emplace(i, i);
    }
    void pop_back() {        
        mapa.erase(prev(mapa.end()));
    }
    void empty() {
        cout << "empty\n";
    }
    void back() {
        cout << "back\n";
    }
    void size() {
        cout << "size\n";
    }
    
};

template<class T>
class MultiMapa {
public:
    multimap<T, T> mapa;
    using value_type = typename T;
    using reference = typename multimap<T, T>::reference;
    using const_reference = typename multimap<T, T>::const_reference;
    using size_type = typename multimap<T, T>::size_type;
    using container_type = multimap<T, T>;


    void push_back(T i) {
        mapa.emplace(i, i);
    }
    void pop_back() {
        mapa.erase(prev(mapa.end()));
    }
    void empty() {
        cout << "empty\n";
    }
    void back() {
        cout << "back\n";
    }
    void size() {
        cout << "size\n";
    }

};

int main()
{
    const int N = 1000000;
    stack<int> s1;
    stack<int, vector<int>> s2;
    stack<int, list<int>> s3;
    
    stack<int, Mapa<int>> s4; 
    stack<int, MultiMapa<int>> s5;
    cout << "Stack:\n";
    test(s1, N);

    cout << "Vector:\n";
    test(s2, N);

    cout << "List:\n";
    test(s3, N);

    cout << "Map:\n";
    test(s4,N); 
    
    cout << "MultiMapa:\n";
    test(s5, N);
}
```

Comment: Notice that even if your wrapper make the code compile, behavior is "broken" (try to see content of the stack). So your benchmarking is useless.